# Regex match only strings with every word capitalized, except for "in", "of"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use a regex expression (javascript) to match ONLY strings where every word is capitalized, except for a couple words ("in", "of") that are allowed to be lower case.

Example:

1. The Quick Brown Fox Jumps [PASS]
2. The quick brown fox
   jumps [FAIL]
3. The Quick brown Fox Jumps [FAIL]
4. The Quick Brown
   of Fox Jumps [PASS]
5. The Quick Brown Fox in [PASS]

I found a regex expression that I frankensteined to "kind-of" work on just the capitalized words part:

```
^\b(?:[A-Z]\w+\b(?:\s*)?)+$
```

However I have no idea how to modify it to allow examples #4 and #5.

Appreciate any help - I'm a first timer!

Comment: Except from the *frankensteining* attempt how much does the OP actually know about `RegExp` (in JavaScript)? Already enough for another approach / try?

Comment: [`/^\s*(?:(?:[A-Z]\w*|a|an|in|of|the|is)\s+)+(?:(?:[A-Z]\w*|a|an|in|of|the|is)?)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/jaIKoe/1)

Comment: Thank you, this was my second attempt but clearly flawed:
^\b(?:[A-Zorf]\w+\b(?:\s*)?)+$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your pattern, and optionally repeat the word chars in case you also want to match a single uppercase char, and use an alternation for the lowercase words that you want to allow.

Then you can repeat that same part preceded by 1 or more whitespace chars.

```
^(?:[A-Z]\w*|in|of)(?:\s+(?:[A-Z]\w*|in|of))*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[A-Z]\w*|in|of)` Match either an uppercase char A-Z and optional word chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
  - `(?:[A-Z]\w*|in|of)` Match either an uppercase char A-Z and optional word chars
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xsiTkB/1)

```js
const pattern = /^(?:[A-Z]\w*|in|of)(?:\s+(?:[A-Z]\w*|in|of))*$/;
[
  "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps",
  "The quick brown fox jumps",
  "The Quick brown Fox Jumps",
  "The Quick Brown of Fox Jumps",
  "The Quick Brown Fox in",
].forEach(s => console.log(pattern.test(s) ? `${s} [PASS]` : `${s} [FAIL]`));
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex, is not the solution to everything, I think it is better to write something  like this in this case:

```js
let sentences = [
  'The Quick Brown Fox Jumps',
  'The quick brown fox jumps',
  'The Quick brown Fox Jumps',
  'The Quick Brown of Fox Jumps',
  'The Quick Brown Fox in'
];

const validateSentence = (sentence) => {
  let words = sentence.split(' ');
  return words.every(word => {
    return word[0] === word[0].toUpperCase()
    || ['in', 'of'].includes(word);
  });
}

sentences.forEach(sentence => {
    console.log(sentence, '=>', validateSentence(sentence));
});
```

Comment: how about `of The Quick Brown Fox`?

Comment: @georg, it is working too, what is the problem ?